# PHP / MYSQL Inserting current time to datetime

Tags: php, mysql, insert

```
$newtime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time() + 600);
mysql_query("UPDATE rounds SET clock = $newtime WHERE `round`='$CurrentRound' ") or die(mysql_error()); //update DB
```

This code is failing to add the current time (+10 mins) to the MySQL database.

The cell in the database is datetime format.

I had done this before, but upon rewriting the code, it has stopped working.

Comment: `... SET clock = '$newtime' ...`

Comment: Consider using PHP's `mysqli_` functions as `mysql_` will be deprecated in the near future.

Answer (score 2):

You could use

`UPDATE rounds SET clock = NOW() + INTERVAL 10 MIN WHERE round = '$CurrentRound'`

To set the clock to 10 mins, per the time on the MySQL server.

Alternatively, you need to add `'` around the `$newTime` variable

`UPDATE rounds SET clock = '$newtime' WHERE round = '$CurrentRound'`

Comment: Exactly what I was going to suggest - take PHP out of the loop.

Comment: The 600 seconds part is actually a variable that has to be in seconds.

Comment: @user2924019, then the second one will fit your need

Answer (score 0):

change your query to this:

```
("UPDATE rounds SET `clock` = '$newtime' WHERE `round` = '$CurrentRound'")
```